# Does not support the required transaction interface

Tags: sql-server-2008, db2, linked-server

I have created a Linked Server between Sql Server 2008 R2 and DB2.

I can do selects and updates from the Query Windows, but if I try to wrap my updated in a BEGIN TRANSACTION - COMMIT TRANSACTION I get the following error:

**The requested operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider "DB2OLEDB" for linked server "DB2" does not support the required transaction interface.**

"DB2" is the name of my Linked Server.

I have tried both using four-part names, e.g.

```
UPDATE [DB2].[TEST].[TEST].[TEST]
SET [COL2] = 2
WHERE [COL1] = 1
```

and using OPENQUERY, e.g.

```
UPDATE OPENQUERY (DB2, 'SELECT [COL2] FROM TEST.TEST WHERE [COL1]=1)
SET [COL2]=2
```

If I just execute the statements it works fine. If I wrap them in a transaction it does not.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I've done some more digging into this issue and the answer is the following:
The DB2OleDB provider from the feature pack does not support transactions, but the HIS (Host Integration Services) does.
Also you have to use DISTRIBUTED TRANSACTIONS and set XACT_ABORT ON before the call to BEGIN DISTRIBUTED TRANS.

An example:

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON
go
BEGIN DISTRIBUTED TRAN
Go
INSERT INTO OPENQUERY (SYS1_DUW, 
      'SELECT * from STROBAEK.DUWTEST') 
      (AREAID, AREADESC,REGIONID) 
      values ('11111', 'Redmond', 101)
ROLLBACK TRAN
Go

exec ('SELECT * FROM STROBAEK.DUWTEST') at SYS1_DUW
Go

AREAID                AREADESC          REGIONID
00001                 BadBoy            104
00002                 BadGirl           105


BEGIN DISTRIBUTED TRAN
Go
INSERT INTO OPENQUERY (SYS1_DUW, 
      'SELECT * from STROBAEK.DUWTEST') 
      (AREAID, AREADESC,REGIONID) 
      values ('11111', 'Bellevue', 101)
COMMIT TRAN
Go       

exec ('SELECT * FROM STROBAEK.DUWTEST') at SYS1_DUW
Go

AREAID                AREADESC          REGIONID
00001                 BadBoy            104
00002                 BadGirl           105
11111                 Bellevue          101


BEGIN DISTRIBUTED TRAN
Go
UPDATE OPENQUERY (SYS1_DUW, 
      'SELECT * from STROBAEK.DUWTEST') 
       set AREADESC = 'Copenhagen' where REGIONID = 101
COMMIT TRAN
Go

SET XACT_ABORT OFF

exec ('SELECT * FROM STROBAEK.DUWTEST') at SYS1_DUW

AREAID                AREADESC          REGIONID
00001                 BadBoy            104
00002                 BadGirl           105
11111                 Copenhagen        101
```

One issue: DTC and Mirror does not work together